# Django permisson on rows depending one or more fields content

Tags: django, django-admin

Use case:"
I have a the standard user model that have a Userprofile model that contains among others the field region that is a ForeignKey to the Region model.
Users can be in permission groups that are standard for Django.

In django-admin user model page the user kalle in the site-admin group can see all users. The user pelle is in the regionA1-admin group can see all users who have their userprofile region set to regionA1."

What is the best practice in django to handle this use case in a secure way?

And it could be other models than User. Regions can be added and deleted. Region is used in this case but could be one or more fields that form the criteria. This shall only apply to the django-admin interface and not when interacting with the database on the regular site.